# Code to check amount of blog posts and add css

Tags: loop, jquery

Is there any sort of jquery I can use to check if there is only one blog post on the page, then to add custom CSS? And if there is more than one, add different CSS?

```
<div class="main-blog top top-fix">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post( '' ); ?>

      <div class="divider over">
        <div class="blog-txt left">
          <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_time( 'F j, Y' ); ?></time>

          <div class="caps blk blog-marg">
            <p href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
          </div> <!-- end #BLOGMARG -->

          <div class="fon">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
          </div> <!-- end #FON -->
        </div> <!-- end #BLOGTXT -->

        <div class="blog-img right">
          <?php
          echo(types_render_field( "blog-image", array("output" => "html") ));
          ?>
        </div> <!-- end #BLOGIMG -->
      </div> <!-- end #DIVIDER -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div> <!-- end #MAINBLOG -->
```

Comment: And why don't you use the class instead?? i.e when you are echoing the posts if there is only one posts assign some class and if more than one assign another class. each class would have separate style.

Comment: What is your markup? What kind of custom CSS do you want to add?

Comment: @dot1 - Not sure how to do that.

Comment: then you need to paste your code here and give details about it.

Comment: @RRikesh - Code backticks not working, HTML is here http://jsfiddle.net/k3GYH/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `$wp_query->found_posts` to get the number of posts in the loop.

```
if( $wp_query->found_posts > 1 ){
  // add css for multiple posts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this would do the trick for you

```
 $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
 if($total_posts = 1){
   $div_class="single-post";
 }elseif($total_posts > 1)}
    $div_class= "multiple-posts";    
 }
```

put it after

```
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post('');
```

so that it would become

```
 <?php 
       while(have_posts()) : the_post('');
       $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
       $div_class = '';
       if($total_posts = 1){
          $div_class="single-post";
       }elseif($total_posts > 1)}
         $div_class= "multiple-posts";    
       }
  ?>
  <div class="divider over <?php echo $div_class; ?>">
```

then echo the $div_class to the particular element you want to add class to.

Comment: Do I close this code with a closing php tag?

Comment: yes you need to do that as you are outputting html after it.

Comment: I'm a little confused, I'm not sure what element in my markup I'd echo either class to; would it be the whole .main-blog div since that surronds each blog post?

Comment: Yes the wrapper div "DIVIDER" for each post content as a new divider div is created for each post, seems like you are not very familiar with coding, I've updated the answer check.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I'm not very familiar with PHP and WP, just starting out. So, an update. What I'm trying to do is have the footer stick to the bottom when there is one blog post, and if there is multiple, just have a top-margin. It's not working, so here is my CSS for that:

    `.footer {        // one blog post
 height: 1.4em;
 background-color: #000;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
    }

    .home .footer,
    .uncategorized .footer {       // multiple blog posts
 height: 1.4em;
 background-color: #000;
 margin-top: 10em;
 position: static;
    }`

Comment: try min-height:300px or something to your wrapper main-blog

Answer (score 0):

A CSS-only approach (based on your markup) to style a post only if it’s the only post:

```
.main-blog > .divider:only-child { }
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child

---

By the way, instead of wrapping each post in a `<div class="divider over">`, it’s better practice to use the [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) function which adds some specific post classes by default and provides hooks for plugins:

```
<div <?php post_class( 'divider over' ); ?>>
```

Comment: Cool, thank you, that is good to know. Is there anyway to target another div (footer) with that declaration? (or with pure CSS?)

Comment: Not until [parent selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) are available.

Comment: Is there anyway I can target another div via jquery with that declaration?

Comment: `if (jQuery('.main-blog > .divider:only-child').length) { /* do whatever you want */ }`

Comment: @Geert- I don't understand, how do I target a parent selector within the brackets?